# how to add both class in one column in GridView widget YII2

Tags: php, yii2

I need to add both serial class and checkbox class in same column. please help me asap.thanks in advance...

```
     <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
        'header' => '',
        'checkboxOptions' => function($model) {
        if($model->featured=="Y"){
          $bool =true;  
        }else{
            $bool =false;  
        }

         return ['checked' => $bool,'value'=>$model->user_id];},'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align: center;font-size: 13px;',],
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
        'header' => 'S.No',
        'headerOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align: center;background-color: #868686;color: white;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;',],
        'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align: center;font-size: 13px;',],
        ],
], ]); ?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. why you need " two columns" in a singole  column ?.. explain better what do you need  please

Comment: In my project, check box and S.No will be in one column,That's why i am asking.please help me to resolve this issue..

Comment: Unfortunately, just as it is formulated, your question is not clear. I can not understand .. so try to formulate your question in a better way

Comment: check that .....  ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'], AND ['class' => 'yii\gridCheckboxColumn'], in same.                                                                           For Example: ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn','yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],

Comment: let me assume that <td><input type='checkbox' name='select[]' ><span>1</span></td>        <td><input type='checkbox' name='select[]' ><span>2</span></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coud be you need format => raw  and use anonymous function for value  like this suggestion

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    'header' => '',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function($model,  $key, $index) {
        return "<input type='checkbox' name='select[]' ><span> <?= $index ?></span>"
    },
     ....
    ],

    .....
], ]); ?>
```

Comment: I used that, But <span>1</span> count not increasing. i just need to increase that count. Thanks in advance...\

Comment: @shahid  a. simple way is use a model attribute for count the row then show this value in your span ..

Comment: can u please give me one example to count model attribute. Thanks in advance

Comment: please help me to resolve this issue. $model->user_id this i given in span, But count is not in order It's show like 1,4,7,9,etc..,

Comment: @shahid   . i have update the answer using $index insidevalue  anonymous function .. could be is this the number you need ... let me know

Comment: It's working, But i have include pagination in my webpage. if i click next page (eg: page no:2) it wil again start with $index value 1. can u please tell me,how to continue the $index until the pagination end...Thanks in advance